# Android XML - Apply and use different buttonStyles

Tags: android, android-layout

At the moment, I feel a little bit stupid.
Here's my problem :
**I actually want to apply different styles for some buttons, different from my default button's style.**

My `styles.xml` :

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CustomTheme.CardViewStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomTheme.StandardButton</item>
    </style>

    <...>

    <style name="CustomTheme.StandardButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ripple_button</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme.ConfirmButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ripple_button_confirm</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomTheme.CancelButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ripple_button_cancel</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In fact, I tried a lot of things with inheritance of my *CustomTheme.ConfirmButton* and *CustomTheme.CancelButton*.

What's changing from *CustomTheme.StandardButton* : the shape's color.
The `ripple_button.xml` is orange.
Then, I created two other *ripple buttons*, **the first one is red** (CancelButton), **the second one is green** (ConfirmButton).

By default, the `<item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomTheme.StandardButton</item>` is applied.

But, in my activity, even when I declare a specific theme to my buttons, the default style is the only one applied. 
*Note : the both buttons are always visible in these activity.*

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm_reset"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_confirm"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_cancel_reset"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        style="@style/CustomTheme.ConfirmButton"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_reset"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn_confirm_reset"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        style="@style/CustomTheme.CancelButton"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to apply the "default" StandardButton theme manually for each button (and then by removing the line `<item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomTheme.StandardButton</item>` from my `styles.xml` but I still get the same behavior : all my buttons are always orange (and using StandardButton theme).

So I'm wondering where I fail / what I don't understand, or even if it's possible.

If a peaceful soul has an idea, some tips, I will be grateful (I can thank my hero with a french craft beer).

Have a great day, and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Button Style as below:

**style.xml**

```
<style name="CustomTheme.StandardButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme.ConfirmButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme.CancelButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">8dp</item>
</style>
```

You missed to append `android:` in item background.

To set Ripple effect you have to use `android:colorControlHighlight` because `android:backgroundTint` will take only color as input and drawable will not work. Here `android:colorButtonNormal` will give no effect because we have set `backgroundTint`. If you will remove `backgroundTint`, it will take color from `android:colorButtonNormal`

**You have to set the theme in `Button` instead of style.**

**your_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm_reset"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_confirm"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.ConfirmButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_cancel_reset"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_reset"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.CancelButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn_confirm_reset"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it will work!!

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, I tried your solution, but the "android:background" hasn't the expected behavior I search. 

You can have a look to what I'm looking for here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B5BS932S5wDU6S11j4QRI9tYrHRbflto
And what your solution does here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P-uOV7HfMcnpA3EneaZBp9wN502w_hjh

So I'm still looking for a solution ^^

Comment: @GeoffreyD.Please check my updated answer. Let me know if you still get any issue.

Comment: Hell yeah ! Your updated answer works very well and let me play with it :)
Thanks ! 
Have a great day @Viraj